# Browsers insert repeatedly '#10;' in base64 string on every new line?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, safari, base64

I want to show on browser already received jpg images coded as Base64. 
1. So I upload jpg images to my backend.
2. Then I want to show that uploaded image on the browser.

On Safari it work properly and I have following inspection:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH_2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH...
```

But on every other browser I can't see the very same image, due to the fact that the other base64 tag has repeated occurances of `#10;` in between the base64 as:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB&#10;AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH_2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB&#10;AQEBAQEBAQE...
```

So other browsers do obviously insert a `#10;` whereever a new line takes place..

I make the uplod from Android Smartphones and I encode to base64 via:

```
Base64.encodeToString(jpgStream.toByteArray(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

**How can I fix that?** Is that backend related or browser or even Android client?

Comment: I'm confused as to whether this is data your server is receiving data from a browser(first line of your question) or sending data to a browser(rest of question). Can you clear up this confusion for me?

Comment: @CaiusJard Rephrased see above

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other transparent process somewhere performing an URL encode on the data in the src attribute?

Comment: @CaiusJard I dont think so, I'll check again. But if so, wouldn't it be broken on Safari browser as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is encoding your `\n` to `&#10;` on the server side, and Safari is removing it again, rather than other browsers adding it in.

This HTML works fine in chrome for me (save it in a file called a.html on your desktop and open it):

```
<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN
  SUhEUgAAAAUA
  AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAA
  AAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
  9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></img></body></html>
```

I think you might need to put more code in your question showing how you retrieve the data, base64 it, incorporate it into the page being sent to browser etc

Also, take a look at the raw responses from your server, in the browser developer tools or a web debugging proxy like Fiddler, to see exactly what your server is sending - using Inspect Element might be showing you the data after it's parsed/interpreted/rendered rather than raw

Comment: It does not have new lines, as you can see in the first code snippet for safari. Other browsers insert the new lines there..

Comment: the second code snippet has multiple `#10;` injected in the string.